# Gazebo Garden : Green line in camera image with OGRE 1 render engine but not with OGRE 2

Tags: sensors, computer-vision, cameras, gazebo

While loading the same map in gazebo garden with ogre 1 or ogre 2, the map looks the same in the GUI, but a green line appears in the camera image when using ogre1 (no distortion or noise applied, default camera parameters).

Any idea why that could be and how to prevent that? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Is the green line in a constant position on the map or in the camera frame?  Is it at the boundary of two polygons lining up?

Comment: Hey! The line is fixed in space so Id say the boundary of 2 polygons lining up (differnt angles of it when moving around, doesnt affect the rest of the map). Just curious why only in OGRE 1 and what I can do to remove or hide it. Thanks!

Comment: So it looks like this happens on all maps (collada, dem, plane) when using ogre 1 for the sensor-systems plugin, the green line ALWAYS starts at the origin (0,0,0), in the y direction, for about 15 meters. When getting closer to it, it looks like it is made of lots of little green dots.

```
<plugin name='gz::sim::systems::Sensors' filename='gz-sim-sensors-system'>
      <render_engine>ogre</render_engine>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: Temporary workaround is to align one of the edges of the map with the origin so that the green line becomes part of the outline of the map

Comment: I'm wondering if the green line is introduced by a mesh or dem. If you remove the meshes and dems, do you still see the line?

Comment: Hi @iche033 , yes the green line always appears at the origin, in the same direction, with the same length, reglardless of which DEM or mesh I load (if any).